# Python Lambda function and ffmpeg command with stdout from jpg to ts file

Tags: python, ffmpeg, aws-lambda

I have a AWS Lambda Python function setup to process jpg and convert it to a ts file.

I followed these instructions https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/media/processing-user-generated-content-using-aws-lambda-and-ffmpeg/ but changed the  command from vfr to cfr conversion to a jpg to ts conversion.

This is the command I am using

`ffmpeg_cmd = "/opt/bin/ffmpeg -r 30000/1001 -loop 1 -i \"" + s3_source_signed_url + "\" -f lavfi -i anullsrc=channel_layout=stereo:sample_rate=48000 -t 30 -vcodec libx264 -crf 23 -s 1920x1080 -r 30000/1001 -g 150 -pix_fmt yuv420p -acodec aac -b:a 96k -ar 48000 -"`

Everything else is basically the same from the AWS article besides having s3 triggers in my Lambda look for jpeg and jpg suffixes.

But this results in 0 byte ts file.

I have a hunch that I need to modify the command that has a seekable output format (e.g. mpegts) when writing to stdout; currently my command is likely not working for stdout and that is why I get an empty ts file. But I am having trouble formatting the command correctly. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I tried using a pipe with mpegts but no luck ```ffmpeg_cmd = "/opt/bin/ffmpeg -r 30000/1001 -loop 1 -i \"" + s3_source_signed_url + "\" -f mpegts - lavfi -i anullsrc=channel_layout=stereo:sample_rate=48000 -t 30 -vcodec libx264 -crf 23 -s 1920x1080 -r 30000/1001 -g 150 -pix_fmt yuv420p -acodec aac -b:a 96k -ar 48000 -"```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to solving this issue was using temporary folders and using subprocess call

Here is the Lambda function code

```
import subprocess
import shlex
import boto3
import os


def lambda_handler(event, context):

    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

    s3_source_bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    s3_source_key = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']


    s3_source_basename = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(s3_source_key))[0]
    destination_bucket = "destination-bucket"
    destination_bucketfile_name = os.path.dirname(s3_source_key) + "/" + s3_source_basename+".ts"

    l_input = "/tmp/" + os.path.basename(s3_source_key)
    l_output = "/tmp/"+ s3_source_basename + ".ts"


    s3_client.download_file(s3_source_bucket,s3_source_key,l_input)
    subprocess.run(['ls','-l','/tmp'])

    ffmpeg_cmd = "/opt/lib/ffmpeg -y -framerate 30000/1001 -loop 1 -i \"" + l_input + "\"" + " -f lavfi -i anullsrc=channel_layout=stereo:sample_rate=48000 -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -s 1920x1080 -r 30000/1001 -g 150 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a aac -b:a 96k -ar 48000 -t 31 -f mpegts " + l_output
    print(ffmpeg_cmd)
    command1 = shlex.split(ffmpeg_cmd)
    p1 = subprocess.call(ffmpeg_cmd, shell=True)

    response="Failed"
    if(p1==0):
        response = s3_client.upload_file(l_output, Bucket=destination_bucket, Key=destination_bucketfile_name)
    else:
        print("Failed Process "+str(p1))

    os.remove(l_input)
    os.remove(l_output)

    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps(response)

    }
```